# How to convert [corona sdk]'s webview into an image?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

adding a webview inside a corona sdk is easy, now I want to convert this webview into an image, and save it into device, how ?

example image

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simply save a screenshot using display.captureBounds

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/captureBounds.html

Comment: thanks, I never knew about this even though I searched well.

Comment: @DeyaEldeen you work with display object a lot. just read through every function of a class you use so you know its full potential. I have never used Corona myself and I already know about it :)

Comment: did you read this ? this is not a solution :(
"
This capture function will only capture what is rendered in OpenGL. It will not capture native display objects such as text boxes, text fields, web popups, ads, etc.
"

I will search for another solution.